# Creating general purpose gant scripts

Tags: grails, ant, build-process, grails-2.2, gant

Is it possible to create gant scripts to automate generalized processes.

e.g. Grails provides a default script 'create-app' to create a project using a tomcat container. Now suppose that I want to write my own script that could create projects using jboss as a server. I would like to save this script in a generalized manner so that I can use it to create more projects, rather than save it under some specific projet.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, save it in `$HOME/.grails/scripts`. This way it will be available to all Grails installs.

Note that the naming convention is important; if the script starts with an underscore, it cannot be called directly as a script, only included in others (e.g. to store common code and methods). If it ends in an underscore, it can be called outside of a project (e.g. the `create-app` script is named `CreateApp_.groovy`). If there's no leading or trailing underscore then it can be called from within a project.